# Add image to blank svg image in leaflet with divIcon

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to create a divIcon to use with leaflet maps. I can create a marker with a blank circle using an SVG image code, but I would like to add an image inside the circle. Is this possible? I have tried background images etc but nothing works.

The code is

```
var iconSettings = {
        mapIconUrl: '<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 149 178"><path fill="{mapIconColor}" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M126 23l-6-6A69 69 0 0 0 74 1a69 69 0 0 0-51 22A70 70 0 0 0 1 74c0 21 7 38 22 52l43 47c6 6 11 6 16 0l48-51c12-13 18-29 18-48 0-20-8-37-22-51z"/><circle fill="{mapIconColorInnerCircle}" cx="74" cy="75" r="61"/><circle fill="#FFF" cx="74" cy="75" r="{pinInnerCircleRadius}"/></svg>',
        mapIconColor: '#cc756b',
        mapIconColorInnerCircle: '#fff',
        pinInnerCircleRadius:48
    };

// icon normal state
var divIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: "leaflet-data-marker",
  html: L.Util.template(iconSettings.mapIconUrl, iconSettings), //.replace('#','%23'),
  iconAnchor  : [12, 32],
  iconSize    : [50, 60],
  popupAnchor : [0, -28]
});
```

Comment: You probably need `L.Icon()`, not `L.DivIcon()`.  DivIcon uses html's DIV element which can have back ground color, rounded corner, and they got used to create circular symbols (open/closed), noting else.  Maybe square symbol can be made, i guess.

Comment: Its ok thanks I did it with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969682/not-adding-custom-marker-with-added-css-with-leaflet-map-and-l-routing-control/53969712#53969712